# questions about Liferay, SVN and Continuous Integration

Tags: eclipse, svn, continuous-integration, liferay

I'm new to CI and to the System admin role in general. At the moment, we have some developer working on multiple Liferay projects, which consist in different plugins and some hooks. 
They use Eclipse with Liferay SDK, a SVN repository , different versions of liferay(from 6.1.2 to 7.0, depending on the project).
Actually they do all the testing on another machine, by manually moving to the testing machine  the .war, after local building.

What I'm asking is: is it possible to setup a tool that, at a scheduled time, will pick a specific tag from the SVN, build it and deploy it remotely on the testing machine? Which tool should be use and how should it be configured?

Thanks very much

Comment: Use bit bucket and git repository for it. If they are using PHP strom , Eclipse etc than they can directly commit their operations using their IDEs on bit bucket or git etc.

Comment: I don't think they wuld switch from SVN to git..

Comment: Yes it is possible. And there are at least as many answers as there are tools for continuous integration out there (some of them you can find in [the Wikipedia category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Continuous_integration)). Please read ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Hi look into Jenkins SVN plugin what are his capabilities if it is able to check out tags. I prefer the use of git where I have a branch that will be used for deployment.

Generally, the flow should be: 
* devs do development in and when they are happy the changes are merged into the deploy branch.
* Jenkins will pick up the change (automatically, time triggered, manually) and check out the repo, build the projects and copy the artefact into the Liferay deploy folder.
* the artefacts get deployed

The only issue is with the DB updates. You need to take care to handle them somehow. There are frameworks that can help you and the DB can be updated as part of the process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't figure out how to manage multiple portlets and deploy them remotely with jenkins and the SVN plugin..

Comment: svn plugin is only for loading the latest code. You need a build plugin depending on your build tool (ant, maven, gradle) and then you need something to do the actual deploy so another deploy plugin (this could do the trick Publish Over SSH Plugin).